# How to fix performance in AJAX based websites for spotty networks?

Tags: json, ajax, rest, single-page-application

I've been traveling for the last couple weeks and have found a issue with the method that Ajax uses to construct a website. I understand that the webpage requesting only the pieces it needs is the most efficient method for the servers but when working in an environment where signal comes and goes or is being throttled by a provider, most websites running on this model become completely unresponsive and turn every interaction into a several minute wait.

In situations where the bandwidth is limited, the best performance generally comes from websites that have all of their content on one single page that is constructed for the user before it is sent. I understand that this is not the restful way but I was wondering if there was a middle ground to this solution.

Is there a way to batch many different AJAX calls where the user would only be sending one large call to the server which then the server would compile everything that is listed and then returns it in one heap? Or is this something that hasn't been formed into a standard yet and a custom server architecture would end up needing to do?

Comment: One option would be to provide a hybrid solution. What i mean by this is The initial page load, regardless of what page you are requesting, is completely rendered server-side. Then, anything you do on the page that needs to change the ui happens through ajax requests. If any of these requests fail, a page refresh would again result in the server rendering the entire page. This is of course easier said than done, unless your server-side language is the same as your client-side language, otherwise you'll have a bit of repeated logic.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where bandwidth is extremely limited, everything you will try to do will be a pain.

Yes, in this scenario, frequently opening connections to the server through multiple requests (which is very typical of ajax single page applications) will make the experience worst than opening one single connection to the server.

However, you need to ask yourself if you want your web application to cater to clients with fast connections or to cater to clients with slow connections and design your web application accordingly. If you make it only to accommodate slow clients then the user experience for those with faster connections will suffer and vice versa.

You could also decide to cater to both audiences by creating a version for each but it's a lot of extra work

I have no idea what your web application does. But if it's to simply "view" data then perhaps you can get away with loading all the data from the start. However, if your web application contains a lot of data manipulation features then you have no choice, stick with Ajax and get a better internet connection.

If you want to *batch* your requests then your web application needs to be designed that way which would allow you to do everything you need to do on the client side before clicking on a "save" button that will gather all the changes you made and send it all in 1 request.

You should always build your web application according to your client's situation. If you're traveling a lot then that might be strictly your problem and won't ever be your client's problem. In this case, stick with ajax and get a better internet connection.

If the client is yourself then heck you could do whatever you want to ease your pain including loading everything from the get go.

Unfortunately there's no magic solution.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The save changes feature might do some good. :) I'm not asking for specifically my situation, (personally I'll go bare bones and keep everything in an ssh tunnel) I'm more asking because I was experiencing a ton of lag in a 3G network online but there are still some parts of the world that are running on 2g and I was curious if there was a software solution to this limitation.